# How to concatenate the "+" operator in a string in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, post, swift2, concatenation

i am making a POST request to the server and my POST string is:

```
let postString = "phone_number=+1234567890&compeleteCode=125435"
```

and in the server side i just return the values of phone_number and completeCode variables but phone_number variable not returns the exact value as i add above it replaces the "+" with space.

And my server side code is:

```
<?php

require "init.php";


$phone_number = $_POST["phone_number"];
$compeleteCode = $_POST["compeleteCode"];


echo $phone_number . ' ' . $compeleteCode;


?>
```

Comment: Try to add \ (slash) before "+". Has it helped?

Comment: Now its shows the error: "invalid escape sequence in literal in swift".

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode your data so it's compatible with being stored as part of a URL. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding